# How to make my plugin dialog window open as QGIS default plugins?

Tags: pyqgis, pyqt4

Actually I mean that:

[image]

As you can see, I make my own plugin and qgis opened my dialog window like second window.

I need somthing like this:
[image]

Here is Validity Check plugin. This is QGIS internal plugin and QGIS didn't open it like second window.

How can I get this?
I look in documentation QT. And [find some interesting flags and functions](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtCore/Qt.html#PySide2.QtCore.PySide2.QtCore.Qt.WindowType) witch can help me, but I can't understand how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `parent=self.iface.mainWindow()` parameter when instantiating dialog.

```
def __init__(self, iface):
    self.iface = iface
    ...

...

def run(self):
    ...
    # change dialog class name
    self.dlg = myDialog(parent=self.iface.mainWindow())
```

Answer (score 1):

you can develop a [Processing Plugin](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/processing.html). By default return this window style

[Another tutorial Link](https://qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/processing_python_plugin.html)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).